# package texlive-latex-extra not present in package repository

Tags: texlive, moderncv

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm trying to use the package `moderncv`, but have trouble compiling. I get an error about missing `etoolbox.sty`, and from what I can read, I need to install a package `texlive-latex-extra`. So I try to install that with `tlmgr` but get the following error.

```
velle@velle-s200e:~/Downloads/moderncv/examples$ tlmgr install texlive-latex-extra
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet
package texlive-latex-extra not present in package repository.
```

I installed texlive with Ubuntu `apt-get`.

Should it not be in the repository, and if not, why?

What do I do from here on?

Comment: Forget about the distribution provided by your package manager. Install the latest TeXLive from [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: Either use `apt-get` and install the package known to it (`texlive-latex-extr`) _or_ use `tlmgr` and install the package know to it (`etoolbox`): the packaging for Linux distro's is not the same as for the TeX Live manager (the latter tends to be at the level of LaTeX-package, whereas the former is 'bundles').

Comment: Ok. I am trying to install manually now; but then having other problems :) Thanks though! :) @JosephWright I started using Thompsons suggestion, but I might get back to yours.

Answer (score 3):

For Debian/Ubuntu there are two options to install TeX Live, with slightly different naming:

- Debian's packages: these are perfectly integrated into the Debian environment, preserve configurations over updates, automatically activate fonts and hyphenation patterns and formats, depending on the set of installed packages, and provide the correct dependencies for other packages. You can install them with `apt-get` or `aptitude`. Management of the packages is *not* done with `tlmgr` but with `apt-get` (for installation) and some configuration files in `/etc/texmf`.

  Naming of the packages is slighlty different in Debian, but can be deduced from the TeX Live collection names by replacing `collection` with `texlive` and adding some separating `-` between different words.

  As example: `collection-fontsextra` becomes `texlive-fonts-extra`, and `collection-langkorean` becomes `texlive-lang-korean` and so on.
- original TeX Live: these have all the above properties, can be installed by normal users without `root` access, and are managed by `tlmgr`. Furthermore, they do not satisfy dependency requirements from other packages (but this can be achieved using `equivs`).

So in your case you should ask your admin to install `texlive-latex-extra`, or if you have `sudo` access, run `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`.